# Преобразовать List<> в Map<String,Integer> с помощью стримов

Tags: java, java-stream

Есть класс Person

```
public Class Person{
    private String name;
    public Person(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }
//getter
}
```

Есть List <Person

Нужно создать Map<String, Integer>  где key это имя из класса Person, а value это количество одинаковых имён. Хочу узнать как это сделать с помощью стримов.
аля `list.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(...))`

циклами это не проблема

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Достаточно открыть документацию метода Collectors.toMap() и всё станет ясно (почему было не сделать этого самому?:)).

Итак, помимо варианта с 2 аргументами:

```
Collector<T, ?, Map<K,U>> toMap(Function<? super T, ? extends K> keyMapper,
  Function<? super T, ? extends U> valueMapper)
```

`Collectors.toMap` имеет ещё и вариант для разрешения конфликтов в случае дубликатов ключей:

```
Collector<T, ?, M> toMap(Function<? super T, ? extends K> keyMapper,
  Function<? super T, ? extends U> valueMapper,
  BinaryOperator<U> mergeFunction)
```

тогда для решения задачи достаточно лишь понять, что при первой встрече имени количество имён = 1, при повторной встрече того же имени (то есть при коллизии ключей) значение должно увеличиваться на 1, тогда получим следующие функции (лямбды) для `valueMapper` и `mergeFunction`:

```
person -> 1
(oldValue, newValue) -> oldValue + 1
```

Для `keyMapper` это всё так же просто получение имени:

```
Person::getName
```

Собрать это всё вместе надеюсь сможете сами, а то пока вопрос выглядит как учебное задание :D

Comment: Спасибо! И вправду в документации есть, пора научиться ее читать.